# PostgreSQL - Array of overlapping Polygon Ids

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a database table (overlay) that has columns, `id::int`, `intersections::int array`, `geom::polygon`.  I have another table (images) that has `id` and `geom` columns. I am trying to populate the `intersections` array with the ids of the rows in the images table that intersect (and have an area greater than 0.00001). For example, if intersection A (overlay table) intersects B1, B2, and B3 (images table), I am trying to set the intersection column in the overlay table to {B1, B2, B3}. The query below is what I have come up with to accomplish this goal,

```
UPDATE public.overlay
SET intersections = array_append(intersections, i.id)
FROM (SELECT geom, id FROM images WHERE images.geom IS NOT NULL) i
WHERE ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(ST_MAKEVALID(overlay.geom), i.geom)) > 0.000001
AND NOT ST_TOUCHES(ST_MAKEVALID(overlay.geom), i.geom)
```

Right now, the above query is only ever adding a single entry to the `intersections` column and I am not sure why. I am going to walk through what I think is occurring in the hopes that my mistake is quite evident:

- `UPDATE public.overlay` <- The table that needs to be updated
- `SET intersections = array_append(intersections, i.id)` <- use the Postgres `array_append` function to update the intersections column. This could also be written as `SET intersections = intersections || i.id`, but that does not result in the desired output.
- `FROM (SELECT geom, id FROM images WHERE images.geom IS NOT NULL) i` <- The `images` table has a few entries with NULL geometries, so skip those. The results of the query are pushed into the `i` variable.
- `WHERE ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(ST_MAKEVALID(overlay.geom), i.geom)) > 0.000001` <- Start of the where clause. Here compute the intersection of the overlay geometry and compute the area so slivers can be omitted.
- `AND NOT ST_TOUCHES(ST_MAKEVALID(overlay.geom), i.geom)` <- The second half of the where clause that omits bordering (touching) polygons. This is redundant, I believe with the area check, but I want to make sure that neighbors are omitted.

Comment: You should probably start by validating your virtual table query.  Does it return what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Going off the suggestion of @Vince, I was able to get this working using the following:

```
UPDATE overlay
SET intersections = imgs.iid
FROM (  
        SELECT overlay.id, array_agg(images.id) as iid
        FROM overlay, images
        WHERE images.geom is NOT NULL AND
        ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(overlay.geom, images.geom)) > 0.000001
        GROUP BY overlay.id
    ) AS imgs
WHERE imgs.id = overlay.id;
```

Since the selection is all at once, an aggregation was the correct approach. The append might be useful in the future if I want to update existing overlaps, but for now, this is a 'one-and-done' operation.

Comment: You will probably get it to run much faster if you put a WHERE ST_Intersects(overlay.geom, images.geom) in the inner query, otherwise you will be calculating the intersection for all combinations of rows from both tables.